# Confusing documentation regarding GA4 to bigquery streaming export limit

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

So the documentation says:

*Standard GA4 properties have a BigQuery Export limit of 1 million events for Daily (batch) exports. There is no limit on the number of events for Streaming export. If your property consistently exceeds the export limit, the daily BigQuery export will be paused and previous days’ exports will not be reprocessed.*

Does this mean all I have to do to circumvent the 1 million event daily export limit is to switch from daily batch exports to streaming exports? This is too good to be true, am I missing something?

Comment: really? no one can answer this question? so disappointing

Comment: I don't have a clear answer but my daily export stopped once. Then I have to use a UDF to backup the intraday (streaming export)

Comment: @ChiếnLê - can you please share details? why did you need to backup the intraday?

Comment: hmmm, tbh I don't know what really happened, but the daily export from GA4 was interrupted (we actually exceeded 1 million events for some days). It's like you have data on 17,18 and then 25; data from 19 to 24 gone missing.

at that time, I didn't know about this limitation. So I created a UDF that runs before midnight to back up the data

Comment: @ChiếnLê so you were able to overcome the 1 million limit simply by backing up the intraday? where did you store this backup? please help!

Comment: @ChiếnLê so you have disabled the daily table and are only working with the streaming option right? then your UDF does a daily backup of the intraday, but where and how do you send this data?

Comment: @Ray92 nah I didn't turn the daily export off. I'm simply using UDF to back up the intraday table (which will be deleted the next day). And I didn't say that I can overcome the 1 million limit. On the reporting side, We also take samples of these data to keep the report light with the metrics close to fact number (acceptable)

Comment: @ChiếnLê - if you are backing up intraday daily, and intraday can go above 1 million, have you not overcomed the limit?!

Comment: @Ray92 I'm not sure about that. FYI I only backed the data 1 time before 00:00 AM, so there should be data gone missing.
You can try to back the data with higher freq to check if you can go above the limit.

Answer (score 1):

I feel this is a confusing trap description. Once your events volume exceeds one million, streaming export will also stop, and Google will force you to upgrade to 360 services. Now I am troubled by this very issue.

Comment: did you experience this personally? i.e. your streaming also stopped once one million events were exceeded

Comment: We faced this, we have 2 projects one does 10M events a day the other is barely above 1M and we got a warning that exports are going to stop. Not sure what we did with the first project to get 10M events streamed.